# bash read lines of data in multiple files exclude subdirectories

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, readline, subdirectory

I use the below code to parse a directory for files and read each line from each file:

```
for file in /tmp/path/*; do
    while read line; do
    [Doing some stuff...]
    done < "$file"
done
```

I am noticing if the directory that I am reading lines from has sub-directories, it tries to read the sub-directories and the script exits with the following error:

```
read: read error: 0: Is a directory
```

I am not sure how to exclude sub-directories when reading lines from multiple files in a directory.  Any help is appreciated...

`

Comment: You < $file should be on the inner done. Use if [ ! -d "$file" ]; then to exclude sub-directories. or use find command in for loop e.g. for file in `find . -type f` to get only regular files

Comment: First: I think you have missed the `in` keyword `for file in /tmp/path/*`. Second: the same the @SameerNaik answered

Comment: @SameerNaik Got it thanks! I used the conditional statement outside the inner loop.  This eliminated sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bash conditions to test if the file is a directory or a "regular" file in each loop iteration, but this will leave you with another problem looming: what if there are a lot of files?  If `/tmp/path/*` expands to lots of (or a few very long) filenames, you will have a problem because there is a maximum command line length limit.

A better way is to use `find`.  Something like this:

```
find /tmp/path -depth 1 -type f | while read file; do
   # ...
```

This way you will never hit the command line length limit (because you never expand in the shell), though you are still left with a problem if you have filenames with newlines in them (the horror!).  If you might have filenames with newlines in, you can try `find -print0`.